# Mitigating Entity Framework EDMX footprint

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, entity-framework-5, edmx

We have used entity framework to build our entity model on our web server. This gets pushed down to clients via wcf. Problem is that over time the edmx has grown and grown until it is a collection of hundreds of tables with mapped relations (its a monster). The problem with this is that it is now very heavy and you can see it sucks up a fair chunk of memory on the web server when it spins it up.

Is there anyway we cut down on the footprint that it has? Splitting it into multiple smaller edmx's is going to be a massive painful task and is last scenario that I would want to play with. Hoping other people have ideas?

We are currently on v5.1 of the entity framework.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you still need all the tables that are in the edmx?

Comment: Yeah, it's a LOB application that hasnt fundamentally changed so all tables are still needed.